# Personal directories on file server for each user in AD

Tags: active-directory, path, directory, windows-server-2003

I want to make a home directory for each user of every group in AD using a batch script.

the users personal directories (my documents, ...) should be stored in there as well.

the path should be as following:

```
\\Fileserver\{group name}\{user name}
```

can someone give me some pointers on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is impossible...

You may not be able to do it with a batch script..but you can with .NET app.

You'll have to read the users and groups from the Active Directory & then use impersonation to create folders on the fileserver for each group/user combo.

Answer (score -2):

This is impossible to solve, I'm very sorry to disappoint you.

Comment: So it isn't possible to retrieve the group from the given user? Maybe with a .NET application.